# Android and cross-compiling

Tags: android, cross-compiling, android-ndk

I have a Linux library that needs to be compiled under Android. I understand that should be used to build this program: / home/user/android-ndk/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc and then compile a ndk-build . I think right? Assembly via the utility should work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Native Development Kit (NDK) and read through the documentation in the NDK about the build process. The NDK  basic info is at http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html, and you'll need to install an appropriate version of Cygwin (if you're using Windows).

It comes with a prebuilt compiler, so you shouldn't have to rebuild that.

Comment: That's understandable. But the question is: compiled by the utility in the NDK (arm-eabi-gcc) with the implementation of ndk-build will work correctly? Question blunt, but just in case I ask.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, that works just fine. Getting the proper makefile put together can sometimes be a pain, particularly if the library you're compiling has a lot of pieces, but it definitely works fine.

Comment: I want to build a fairly complex library. I have a few problematic issues. With you can talk (in ICQ, Scype, e-mail or anywhere else)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can chat a bit, but it will have to be very short: NDK debugging can easily take many hours for even simple libraries and typically gets harder with more complex libraries. Look for the chat room kyborg2011 NDK (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/765/kyborg2011-ndk?tab=general)

Comment: Thank you. I wrote to the room.

Comment: Left you a response in the room: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811009/how-to-write-debug-android-mk-for-ndk-static-library/5811861#5811861 for an example Android.mk file (this is for libpng) that works using the NDK. You can't really write a build script in the style you're trying (or rather, you can, it would just be very very very hard to get right), so take a look at the NDK documentation.html file and figure out how to get your library built using the Android.mk file: you'll be glad you did.