# Build Linux library to Android

Tags: java, android, linux, java-native-interface

I have C library project for Linux (with jni). I need to build this library for Android.
But it's impossible to use Makefile.in for ndk-build.

I've found two ways - one is to create makefiles Makefile.mk for this project, another one is to set some flags, and choose a toolchain to build project with existing structure and makefiles for ARM processor.

So the question, how can be done the second way? Or maybe some example of porting existing projects to Android.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find documentation on how to use the Android Toolchain in <your-ndk-folder>/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html.

Comment: Did you check this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899206/android-and-cross-compiling