# Precompiling static library in Android NDK - sources in separate directory tree

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries

I am trying to precompile a static library using the Android NDK. This precompiled static library will later be linked with JNI code in other projects. I do not have an Eclipse project associated with the library so I set up a skeleton Android JNI directory structure within the library's project root directory.
The directory structure is as follows:

```
<root>/
       Android/
               jni/
                   Android.mk
                   Application.mk
       iOS/
           <other stuff here>
       src/
           <a bunch of *.c and *.h files here>
```

This is the `Application.mk` file:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

And this is the `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := imajilib
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK
MY_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../src/*.c)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2 -llog
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ignore_this_imajilib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := imajilib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The `ignore_this_imajilib` shared library module is a dependency trick I picked up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811009/how-to-write-debug-android-mk-for-ndk-static-library).

I compile the library by cd'ing to the `jni/` directory and running the following command:

```
~/path/to/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/path/to/<root> -B V=1
```

The compilation succeeds with no issues. I now have new directories `libs/` and `obj/` under the `jni/` directory.

The structure of the `libs/` directory is:

```
libs/
     armeabi-v7a/
                 libignore_this_imajilib.so
```

This is okay but ideally I would like to see `libimajilib.a` here as well.

The structure of the `obj/` directory is:

```
obj/
    local/
          armeabi-v7a/
                      libignore_this_imajilib.so
                      libimajilib.a
                      objs/
                           imajilib/
                                    <this directory is empty>
                      src/
                          <a bunch of *.o and *.o.d files>
```

The problem is with the location of the `*.o` and `*.o.d` files. I suspect the build process is placing them there because of the `../../src/*.c` that I have in the `Android.mk` file, and so it is going to `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/imajilib/../../src` whereas I would like to see them in `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/imajilib`. I see no way around this other than to copy and paste the source files from `src/` to the `jni/` directory, but I don't want to do this as the `src/` directory is shared among multiple platforms.