# Cannot build static library with Android NDK R8

Tags: android-ndk, static-libraries

I have been building a shared library with the Android NDK and now want to build it as a static library. I assumed that all I had to do was change **BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY** to **BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY** in Android.mk but now when I run `ndk-build`, absolutely nothing happens. It just comes right back to the command prompt without displaying anything. I tried `ndk-build -n` and it shows 3 `rm` commands being executed and nothing else. I tried `ndk-build -B` and it makes no difference. I tried `ndk-build -d` and there is nothing in the output related to my source files or the name of the library.

If I change the make file back to build the shared library, it compiles the source and links the .so with no problems.

Anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that in order to build a static library, it must be a dependency of something. I was able to build my library as static by adding an Application.mk file with the following line:

> APP_MODULES = mylib